# Redirect with custom link to an external source and track the redirect

Tags: nginx, web, google-analytics

I want to share links like www.domain.com/twitter/headline where twitter/headline represents the link I put in my twitter headline. Then I use something like nginx to configure what would happen. I want to redirect the source to an external page like a profile and I want to track how many people clicked the link with something like bitly or google analytics or does anyone know an elegant solution for my use case?

Problems with bitly
1. You can not have two links for the same destination. So let's pretend I have domain.com/twitter/a and domain.com/twitter/b and both redirect to two bitly links that forward to my linkedin profile. This does not work.

Problems with Google Analytics
1. ga is not made to track redirects. it can track where the traffic comes from but since I forward to external sources like linkedin I cannot put a ga code on my linkedin profile to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understsand the entire flow.
You can use a service like anytrack.io.

- it will track the incoming traffic landing on your page (very much like GA does), and
- track the outbound clicks to wherever you send the visitors.
- Then it will tie the events to your GA account.

Not sure if that's what you wanted to do...

Comment: I found an app "visitors" that analyze your nginx log files and tells you how many people visited your site or your certain link. I would still prefer a site like GA but I do not know how to configure GA to do what I want.